# How to verify oauth token generated using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, token, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting the oath token using below code:

```
def get_token():

    try:
    
        r = requests.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + config_data['TENNANT_ID'] + "/oauth2/token",
        
            data={"grant_type": "client_credentials",
                  "client_secret": config_data['CLIENT_SECRET'],
                  "client_id": config_data['CLIENT_ID'],
                  "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com"})
                  
        if r.status_code == 200:
            ret_body = r.json()
            return ret_body['access_token']
            
        else:
            log.error("Unable to get token from oauth {}, {}".format(r.status_code, r.json()))
            return "false"
            
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Exception occurred while getting oauth token {}".format(e))
```

I am looking for a microsoft graph api through which I can verify the generated oauth token weather its expired or not. Can anyone please point me to some documentation page for this.?

Comment: response body (ret_body) must contain other attributes like expiresIn ,expiresOn, resource etc. You could leverage those attributes

Comment: @Despicableme Actually I have another scenario. I will only received the access_token and not the attributes so I just have to use the access token to verify if its valid or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Despicable in comments, when you access the token, the response json conntains a field `expires_in`. Below is the screenshot of response json when I request for access token, the value of `expires_in` is 82799 in my side but it may be 3599(1 hour) in your side.

[image]

You can use `ret_body['expires_in']` in your code to get the field.

============================**Update**================================

As you can only receive the access token but not any more fields, so you can parse(decode) the access token to get the expire date.

When we parse the token in [this](https://jwt.io/) page for test, we can find there is a claim `exp`(in timestamp format) which means the expire date of the token. So we just need to parse the token and get the property `exp`, then convert it from timestamp to datetime.
[image]

Below is part of my code for your reference:

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    ret_body = r.json()
    accessToken = ret_body['access_token']
    decodedJson = jwt.decode(accessToken, verify=False)
    timestamp = decodedJson["exp"]
    resultDateTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

The `resultDateTime` is the expire time of your access token, you can compare it with current time(you can also skip change timestamp to datetime format in your code, compare the timestamp with current date timestamp directly).

To execute the code success, you also need to install `pip install pyjwt` and add these lines in your python code:

```
import jwt
import json
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: I will only receive the access token so I need to find some way to verify it if its valid or not

Comment: Hi @SAndrew I will update my answer later for your requirement.